# Oracle DB link: Error line missing

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, dblink

We have a DB link between 2 Oracle 11.2 databases.

On the production system, we noticed that when an `UPDATE` statement of a remote table fails in an PL/SQL procedure (started as a scheduled job), the error message is lost.

Example code:

```
UPDATE remote_table@our_db_link SET ...
exception
when others then
  senderror('Error: '|| sqlerrm || chr(10) || dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace || chr(10) || sys.DBMS_UTILITY.format_call_stack);
```

The `senderror` procedure saves the supplied text to a log file.

There we see:

```
Error: ORA-01536: space quota exceeded for tablespace 'TS1'
ORA-02063: preceding line from OUR_DB_LINK
ORA-06512: at "X_TEST.X_PACKAGE", line 64

----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0x89b0bca0       114  package body X_TEST.X_PACKAGE
0x7d5b27e8         1  anonymous block
```

This is what we get on the test system. On the production, the root cause is missing, so the text is:

```
Error: ORA-02063: preceding line from OUR_DB_LINK
ORA-06512: at "X_TEST.X_PACKAGE", line 64

----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0x89b0bca0       114  package body X_TEST.X_PACKAGE
0x7d5b27e8         1  anonymous block
```

The DB version is 11.2.0.4.

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Is it possible that, on the production system, the user does not have EXECUTE permission on the DBMS_UTILITY package?

Comment: @MJH No, because then the result of `format_error_backtrace` and `format_call_stack` would not be present in the log file.

Comment: Could you compare the code between test and prod for senderror procedure?

Comment: @DavidBalažic, do you have any updates for this issue? I faced with the same behavior but my understanding is that remote SQL query contains references to objects (especially packages) at origin side.

Comment: @drnk Sadly, no.